# Trim the top and bottom white space only in a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to trim the top and bottom white space only in a matplotlib plot before saving it? That is, save the figure to the same width as `figsize`, but the best fit height?

I am currently using the following code, however, it saves a figure that is 10" (1000px) tall.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize = (6, 10))
plt.imshow(np.zeros((1000, 1000)))
plt.savefig('short_plot.png', dpi=100)
```

Changing the last line to `plt.savefig('short_plot.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight)` results in a figure that is 6.11" by 6.04". However, I need my figure to be exactly 6" wide.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were going for:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)
plt.imshow(np.zeros((1000, 1000)))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('short_plot.png', dpi=100)
```

This results in an image that's defined to be 600x600 pixel (6x6 inches, at 100dpi) and after providing the data to display, the layout is tightened (which is what you seem to want to achieve with `bbox_inches='tight'`.

The `.savefig('short_plot.png', dpi=100)` writes a .png of exactly 600x600 pixels.

Comment: Thanks! You answer assumes that we know the aspect ratio of the image beforehand (6:6), where in the question it was unknown. That is probably the only way to go then, calculate the aspect ratio of the image and then set the size of your figure to that same ratio.

Comment: I did not so much assume as I inferred. Since your dataset is n:n (1000:1000) and you don't specify a separate ratio for x and y axis, it stands to reason that the resulting diagram will have an n:n ratio as well. Since you force it to 6" on the shorter side (and say you need it to be exactly 6" wide) and specify a 100dpi resolution, it simply has to be 600x600, without assumptions. You're welcome though - if you feel this answers the question, please consider clicking the checkmark, so your question no longer appears as unanswered.